# Is Lebesgue outer measure continuous from above for sets with finite Lebesgue outer measure

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Does there exist a decreasing sequence  of sets ($A_{n+1}\subseteq A_n$) ; $\{A_n\}$ of real numbers such that

$m^*(A_n)<\infty , \forall n \in \mathbb N$ and $m^*(\cap_{n\in \mathbb N} A_n) < \lim_{n\to \infty} m^*(A_n)$ ? Here $m^*$ is the Lebesgue outer measure on real line

Answer (score 8):

Let $V$ be the [*Vitali set*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_set#Measurable_sets) which is formed by chooseing a representative within $[0, 1]$ for each coset of $\Bbb{R}/\Bbb{Q}$. Also, let us enumerate $\Bbb{Q} \cap [-1, 1] = \{q_1, q_2, \cdots \}$ and define $\{V_n\}$ by

$$ V_n = q_n + V = \{ v + q_n : v \in V\}. $$

Here are some observations:

- Since the Lebesgue outer measure is translation-invariant, $\{V_n\}$ has the common outer measure $m^*(V_n) = m^*(V)$.
- For each $x \in [0, 1]$ there is a unique $v \in V$ such that $x - v \in \Bbb{Q}$. Since $x - v \in [-1, 1]$, this tells that $x - v = q_n$ for a unique $n$ and hence $x \in V_n$.
- From the previous observation, we have

  $$ [0, 1] \subseteq \cup_{n=1}^{\infty} V_n \subseteq [-1, 2]. $$

  If $V$ were measurable, we would have had $1 \leq \infty \cdot m(V) \leq 3$, which is impossible. Therefore $V$ is non-measurable. Also notice that this implies $m^*(V) > 0$, for otherwise $V$ is a null-set and hence measurable.

Finally, define $\{ A_n \}$ by

$$ A_n = \cup_{k=n}^{\infty} V_k. $$

Then $\{ A_n \}$ decreases to $\varnothing$, and $V_n \subset A_n$ implies that $m^*(A_n) \geq m^*(V_n) = m^*(V)$. Therefore

$$ m^*(\varnothing) = 0 < m^*(V) \leq \lim_{n\to\infty} m^*(A_n). $$

Comment: I believe you have found an example of continuity. This does not imply continuity in general. There are also many trivial examples.

Comment: @fdzsfhaS This is a counterexample, as in this case $m^*(\bigcap_nA_n) < \lim_{n\to\infty}m^*(A_n)$. That is, we do *not* have continuity.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach:

Let $B$ be a basis of $\mathbb{R}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ such that $1\in B$. Define $G=\mathrm{span}_{\mathbb{Q}}(B \backslash \{1\})$. Then $\{G+q | q\in\mathbb{Q}\}$ forms countably many cosets of $G$ partitioning $\mathbb{R}$. Let
$$
A_n=[0,1]\cap\left( \cup \{ G+q | q\in\mathbb{Q}, \  q>n \}\right).
$$
Then 
$$
\cap_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n = \emptyset \ \mathrm{and} \ \  m^*(A_n)=1 \ \ \mathrm{for} \ \mathrm{all} \ n\in\mathbb{N}.$$
The last statement follows from the answer to your other question: [$G$ be a non-measurable subgroup of $(\mathbb R,+)$ ; $I$ be a bounded interval , then $m^*(G \cap I)=m^*(I)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2101953/g-be-a-non-measurable-subgroup-of-mathbb-r-i-be-a-bounded-interval)

In fact, $m^*([0,1]\cap (G+q)) = m^*([0,1]\cap G)= 1$ for all $q\in\mathbb{Q}$.